# getResources(); error

Tags: android

Im trying to create a widget and i get a error when trying to use the Resources res = getResources(); It says its undefined in widget so i'd like to know what i could sub it for. It would be easier to ask in chat but no one is in the android chat on here

Anyway heres my code:

```
package kevin.erica.box;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;



public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    Resources res = getResources();



private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();
private static final Random rgenerator2 = new Random();
private String[] myString1;

private String[] myString2,



myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray);




  public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    Log.i("ExampleWidget",  "Updating widgets " + Arrays.asList(appWidgetIds));
    // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this
    // provider
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
      // Create an Intent to launch ExampleActivity
      Intent intent = new Intent(context, Widget.class);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
      // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
      // to the button
      RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widgetlayout);
      views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imagewidgeterica, pendingIntent);
      // To update a label
      views.setTextViewText(appWidgetId, myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)]);
      // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app
      // widget
      appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the lines:

```
Resources res = getResources();
myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray);
```

To the `onUpdate` method:

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
{
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    if (myString == null)
    {
        myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray);
    }
    // ...
}
```